# Threading is not printing right value

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, python-multithreading

Here below I've written a piece of python multi-threading code. My main objective was to copy the value from q1 to q2 and print both the value using another thread 2 and also the printing from thread 1 in desired order as I've shown below.

```
import threading
import queue

count= 0
q1=queue.Queue()
q2=queue.Queue()

def copying_file(q1,q2,count):
    for i in range(5):
        count=count+1
        q1.put(count)
        for i in q1.queue:
            q2.put(i)
        print("jai shree ram")

def checker(q1,q2):
    while True:
        item=q1.get()
        value=q2.get()
        print(f"Here is the data {item}")
        print(f"Copy ho gya {value}")
        q1.task_done()
        q2.task_done()

t1 = threading.Thread(name='copying', target=copying_file, args=(q1,q2,count))
t2 = threading.Thread(name='checking', target=checker, args=(q1,q2))
t1.start()
t2.start()
q1.join()
q2.join()
```

I wanted to print like this

> ```
> jai shree ram
> Here is the data 1
> Copy ho gya 1
> jai shree ram
> Here is the data 2
> Copy ho gya 2
> jai shree ram
> Here is the data 3
> Copy ho gya 3
> jai shree ram
> Here is the data 4
> Copy ho gya 4
> jai shree ram
> Here is the data 5
> Copy ho gya 5
> ```

But it is printing something like this. Sometimes it is printing other value.All though I've tried other methods but none of them working

> ```
> jai shree ram
> Here is the data 1
> jai shree ram
> jai shree ram
> jai shree ram
> jai shree ram
> Copy ho gya 1
> Here is the data 2
> Copy ho gya 2
> Here is the data 3
> Copy ho gya 2
> Here is the data 4
> Copy ho gya 3
> Here is the data 5
> Copy ho gya 2
> ```

and also the thread is not ending

Comment: system may run threads in random order. If you have to keep order then maybe don't use threads at all. OR maybe you should use queue to send message back to first thread - and this way you can control when it will be executed. Eventually module `threading` has some objects `semaphore`, `lock`, etc to communicate between threads. All this only shows that threads are not easy.

Comment: In "copying_file" you shouldn't copy everything from "q1" to "q2" which is currently available in every for-iteration.

Comment: in expected result it looks like one function has to wait for result from other function - and this can mean that threads are useless and you should do all in one function.